# Getting the Missing positional argument error

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from src.view import *
from src.view import View
from src.model import Model
from pubsub import pub
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

class Controller:
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        # Variables
        self.model = Model(controller=self) #point to Model Object
        self.view = View(controller=self) #point to view object

    def uploadAction(self, audios):
        for audio in audios:
            path = os.path.split(audio)
            audio = path[1]
            self.view.add_audio(audio)



`Model file`
class Model:
    def __init__(self, controller):
        self.controller = controller



`View file`
class View:
    def __init__(self, container, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        self.annotation_box = None
        super().__init__(container)
        self.setup()
        # set the controller
        # self.controller = None

    def setup(self):
        #this class will run first
        #calling the methos to setup the user interface
        self.create_menu()
        self.create_panedwindow()
        self.create_audio_frame()
        self.create_transcript_frame()
        self.create_annotation_frame()
        self.setup_menu()
        self.setup_panedwindow()
        self.setup_audio_frame()
        self.setup_transcript_frame()
        self.setup_annotation_frame()



`Main file`

from tkinter import *

from src.view import View
from src.model import Model
from src.controller import Controller

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_window = Tk()
    main_window.geometry('1400x800')
    main_window.title("Interview Elicitation Tool")
    # controller = Controller(main_window)

    view = View(Controller)
    model = Model(Controller)
    controller = Controller(model, view)
    main_window.mainloop()
`
```

I am getting
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\santh\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\MVC-IET\src\main.py", line 13, in 
view = View(Controller)
TypeError: View.**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'controller'

I tried to add controller=self in main.py also it is not working.
i am new to python. I don't know what to do

Comment: You need to pass both Container and Controller as arguments to create a view instance in `view = View(Controller)`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to pass the model and view to the controller since the controller creates them.  Or, if you want to create them outside of the controller, then the controller shouldn't create them. Choose one method or the other, not both.

Comment: Does this help? `view = View(Model,Controller)`

Comment: That error "View.init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'controller'" clearly says what's wrong. You should understand what it means, before you try to implement a class.

Comment: I passed both container and controller in the view. it solved the issue. Thank you